# Change UIAlertView selector from didDismissWithButtonIndex

Tags: ipad, uialertview

Is it possible to change the selector of a UIAlertView without having to create a custom alert view subclass?

I want to change it from didDismissWithButtonIndex to something else.

Comment: Why? Just implement the method and call whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't even do it with a custom subclass. The only practical way to do this is to create a proxy object that implements the selector and calls a different one, and forwards all other selectors on unchanged. But there's no reason to ever actually do this.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to set custom selectors to different UIAlertViews.
My answer to this problem was to make each specific UIAlertView an autoreleased field of my main view controller calling class. This way, when the delegate method - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex is called, I use the alertView field as a guard to call the right method.